# Clicking a link inside a frame works in debug mode but not otherwise

Tags: python, firefox, selenium, webdriver, selenium-webdriver

I am using the following: Selenium 2.33.0, Python 2.7.3, Firefox 21.0, Debian Wheezy:

Using selenium, I have to click on a logout button which is inside a frame to logout of the site. The below code works in debug mode. In normal mode, the script executes the below logout method without raising any exceptions but the Logout() JavaScript method isn't being executed.

Can any one either point out what I am doing wrong, or suggest a better or alternative way to accomplish the logout functionality using selenium.

The following code works only in debug mode:

```
class BankInfo:
   ...
   logout_btn_selector='//a/img[@src="preferred/gif/logoutbtn.gif"]/..'
   ...

class Automaton():

    self.browser = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_profile=self.get_browser_preferences()) 
    self.bank_info = BankInfo

    def click_button_by_xpath(self, btn_xpath):
        btn = self.browser.find_element_by_xpath(btn_xpath)
        btn.click() 

    def logout(self, logout_btn_selector):
        self.browser.switch_to_default_content()
        self.browser.switch_to_frame('common_menu1')
        self.click_button_by_xpath(logout_btn_selector)

    def execute(self):
        ...
        self.logout(self.bank_info.logout_btn_selector)
    ...

if __name__ == '__main__':
    Automaton.execute()
```

The markup for the page in which the button resides:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added a the following line in get_browser_preferences() method:
        firefox_profile.set_preference("browser.download.useToolkitUI", True)

I suspect that the download window which has the link "Show all downloads" was preventing the selenium webdriver to click on the logout button which was underneath the download window. The above setting prevented the download window from showing up.